# Get data from within a $.get function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

So I have a $.get function, which is successfully passing the data back and I'm able to use the data so long as it is processed directly within the $.get function. Is there any way I can pass this data to a global variable?

Comment: You can use `window.variable="ajax_data"` to set a global variable in JS

Comment: keep in mind though that you can't run your `$.get` call and then immediately try to use `window.variable` in code after it, since the var won't be popped until after the `$.get` call successfully receives a resonse

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: @SLaks well, you "can" .. it's just not very useful to do it in practice!

Comment: The problem I'm having is that the $.get is getting data to fill the table and is then supposed to add that data to the variable I have which contains all the HTML for the table. This variable is then used as $(table).html(htmlvariable)

Comment: @TheBritishBloke then see the question I've linked, please.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak I've been going through it, but I just can't figure out the explanation of how to implement it.

Comment: I've managed to implement it as it says, and managed to get it working. However it still doesn't help me because the table gets generated before the ajax call is complete.

Comment: If you want to do something after an AJAX call is complete, put it into the callback that you pass to the AJAX call.

Comment: It still caused the problem of it ending the javascript, and coming back to it once the call was complete, meaning any variables that existed had now been reset. I ended up having to use async:false. It's not for a very big table, and it seems to work ok. I can PM you a link to the site if you have any advice.

Answer (score 4):

```
var storage;
$.get('/some/url', function(data) {
    storage = data;
});
```

**NOTE:**

Because `$.get` is asynchronous, don't expect `storage` to have anything in it even after executing the `$.get`

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

```
$.get("http://url.com/page", {}, function(data){
 window.variableName=data;
});
```

You can access the global variable by :

```
window.variableName
```

Or

```
variableName
```

### Method 2

```
var variableName;
$.get("http://url.com/page", {}, function(data){
 variableName=data;
});
```

Since `$.get` is asynchronous, the `variableName` will only have value when the response is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this, and you need to understand [Javascript object scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

```
var returnedData;
$.get("url", function(data){
   returnedData =  data;
});
```